# How to update an Entity after another Entity update in Spring Data?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to perform an Update to an entity after another related entity is updated.

I have two entities: `OrderEntity` and `CustomerOrderEntity`, in a relation of 1:N.
Both have an `status` field. `OrderEntity` status depends of all children's status field. So, if one `CustomerOrderEntity` is updated, I need to recalculate the new status of `OrderEntity` and persist/update it.

I have implemented a listener:

```
public class CustomerOrderEntityEnventHandler {

    private OrderService orderService;

    @PostUpdate
    public void handleAfterSave(CustomerOrderEntity customerOrder) {
        OrderEntity order = customerOrder.getOrder();
        OrderStatus newStatus = calculateNewStatus(order);
        order.setStatus(newStatus);
    }

        //other methods and DI handler for orderService. The injection is fine.
}
```

The listener is annotated in `CustomerOrderEntity` and it is being called properly. However, after the process is completed, `OrderEntity` remains the old status even the `orderRepository.save()` is called with the correct new status.

I expect orderEntity to be updated with new status.

UPDATE:
I change the implementation to use `PostUpdateEventListener`. It is being invoked properly, however, the "other" entity is not being updated still.

```
public class CustomerOrderEntityUpdateEnventListener implements PostUpdateEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof CustomerOrderEntity) {

            Session session = event.getSession();
            CustomerOrderEntity customerOrder = (CustomerOrderEntity) event.getEntity();
            OrderEntity order = customerOrder.getOrder();
            OrderStatus newStatus = calculateNewStatus(order);
            order.setStatus(newStatus);

            session.saveOrUpdate(order);
        }
    }

//other methods
}
```

Note that the updated entity is `CustomerOrderEntity` and I want to update  `OrderEntity`.

Comment: This may not answer your question, but the above is exactly why aggregate roots were invented.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it will work for other entities. JPA specification says the following:

> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager or query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence context. A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship state of the entity on which it is invoked.

Comment: Oh, nice input. Do you know a workaround to achieve my requirement?  Basically I need to "trigger" some services after a post, to keep both states synchronized.

Comment: Best option is to call both methods in same service method. Another option is database trigger. A third option is to use another Entity manager but it should be last resort.